# How to do webscraping several webpages at once when there is no pattern in the URLs?

Tags: r, for-loop, web-scraping, lapply, rvest

I want to web scrape the following web pages using R

```
# 1st page - https://www.immobilienscout24.at/regional/wien/wien/wohnung-kaufen
# 2nd page - https://www.immobilienscout24.at/regional/wien/wien/wohnung-kaufen/seite-2
# 3rd page -https://www.immobilienscout24.at/regional/wien/wien/wohnung-kaufen/seite-3
# ......
# 100th page -https://www.immobilienscout24.at/regional/wien/wien/wohnung-kaufen/seite-100
```

to web scrape 1st page I used this part of the code

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
appartmentlink <- "https://www.immobilienscout24.at/regional/wien/wien/wohnung-kaufen"
page <- read_html(appartmentlink)appartmentaddress1 <- page %>% html_elements(".YqNih") %>% html_text()
```

I tried to get the 1st page on the browser by adding  "/seite-1 and /seite-0" to the "1st page" URL but it does not work.

From 2nd page to 100th page I used this code to extract the data (the addresses)

```
appartmentaddress <- lapply(paste0('https://www.immobilienscout24.at/regional/wien/wien/wohnung-kaufen/seite-', 2:100),
                    function(url_base){
                      url_base %>% read_html() %>% 
                        html_elements('.gTYeB') %>% 
                        html_text()
                    })
```

How can I include the 1st page into this block of code, or is there another way to web scrape from 1st page to 100th page in a loop?
Also note that on the 1st page the the element for address is ".YqNih" while in other pages it is ".gTYeB"

Comment: Why not just `c("link_of_your_first_page", paste0("link_for_other_pages", 2:100))`?

Comment: I was able to scrape address using a single node `.YqNih` for both first and second webpage

Comment: I just checked, Up to the 4th page the element is ```.YqNih``` from the 5th page it's  ```.gTYeB```. Thank you "Nad Pat" for the tip. Now I understood why I didn't receive data before.

Comment: @ekoam I do not understand the method you suggested. Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: You just want to include the first page in the loop right? So instead of writing `paste0("...", 2:100)`, we write `c("https://www.immobilienscout24.at/regional/wien/wien/wohnung-kaufen", paste0("...", 2:100))`. Previously I thought you can use the same CSS. Since you cannot do so, use `mapply`, Then the code becomes something like this: `links <- c("https://www.immobilienscout24.at/regional/wien/wien/wohnung-kaufen", paste0("...", 2:100)); css <- c(".YqNih", rep(".gTYeB", 99)); mapply(function(link, css) link %>% read_html() %>% html_elements(css) %>% html_text(), links, css)`. @manojrasika